# Using uniq! on collection with two parameters

Tags: ruby

At this point I am using uniq! to get the unique elements in a collection. Is is possible to get the unique elements based on two parameters? In other words, I would like to use uniq! to get "unique" elements based on both t.info and t.name.

```
 collection.uniq! {|t| t.info }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare an array of those parameters:

```
T = Struct.new :info, :name
collection = [
  T.new('a', 'b'),
  T.new('a', 'b'),
  T.new('a', 'a'),
]

collection.uniq! { |t| [t.info, t.name] }
#=> [#<struct T info="a", name="b">, #<struct T info="a", name="a">]
```

Comment: Any idea why collection.uniq! { |t| t.info && t.name } does not produce the desirable result? For your example it does, but not with mine.

Comment: @JacksonHenley Because it will just return the last of the two which is non-`nil`, so, assuming both are non-`nil`, the return value of the boolean expression is always `t.name`, so you’re effectively `uniq`ing over `t.name` *only*.

Comment: @JacksonHenley As a better proof-of-point, consider what `collection.map { |t| t.info && t.name }` returns, and then what calling `uniq` on it gives you.

Comment: That illustrates it nicely. I have some reading/practice ahead of me when i comes to Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'pp'
require 'ostruct'                                                               

a = OpenStruct.new(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)
b = OpenStruct.new(a: 2, b: 2, c: 3)
c = OpenStruct.new(a: 1, b: 2, c: 4)

pp [a, b, c].uniq                    # all different
pp [a, b, c].uniq { |t| [t.a, t.b] } # a and c are same
```

Comment: OStruct dumps the method cache and should generally be avoided.

Comment: +1, basically the same answer as me and at basically the same time. And @ChrisHeald yea, but it’s just contrived data in an example, after all—arguably what OStruct is best for `:)`.

Comment: @ChrisHeald: As Andrew says, I wouldn't use OStruct in production code, and OP has his own class to deal with and won't be copying my examples literally.

Comment: Aha, fair enough. I'm just slightly allergic to it. :)